# Deserialize an array acts as deserializeStrict

Tags: apex, json

The following throws an error:

```
String request = '{"Id": "0036D00000H24cKQAR","FirstName": "firstName", "someArray":["obj"]}';
Contact c = (Contact)JSON.deserialize(request, Contact.class);
System.debug(c);
```

The error:

```
System.JSONException: No field name specified on column for sobject of type Contact
```

I'm using `deserialize` not `deserializeStrict` so ideally, the array should be ignored right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that the array should be ignored [as mentioned in the [apex developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm?search_text=JSON)]:

*When deserializing JSON content into an Apex class in any API version, or into an object in API version 35.0 or later, no exception is thrown. When no exception is thrown, this method ignores extraneous attributes and parses the rest of the JSON content.*

Infact, this issue was raised as a bug before few years and was fixed in Winter 16 release. Refer [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5QCAA0&title=apex-json-bug-deserialize-to-an-sobject-acts-like-deserializestrict). However, the issue was fixed only for primitive non-array types & empty arrays i.e., if you specified an empty array `"someArray":[]` or a string attribute  `"someArray":"obj"` in your JSON, then the deserialize works as mentioned in the developer guide. But doesn't work in the case of array or for deeply nested JSON elements. ***In your case, you would have to go with JSON.deserializeUntyped and then parse the `Map<String, Object>` returned***.

Could you raise this as a bug with Salesforce?